# Neumorphic / neomorphic design in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I've seen several articles recently about neomorphic design in Flutter. How do I implement that in my own project?

[image]

I know it is something about the `decoration`, but what specifically do I add?

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    ???
  ),
),
```

Comment: check 1. https://pub.dev/packages/clay_containers 
   2. https://pub.dev/packages/neumorphic    3. https://pub.dev/packages/nm_generators

Comment: @Dev, Very nice. I missed those. (I was using the wrong spelling--neomorphic--when I searched pub the first time).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can play around with the actual colors but here is a light and dark example. If you see a different color scheme you like better then just take a screenshot and use Gimp or some other image editing software to get the hex colors from it.

## Neumorphic light

[image]

- Background color: `Color(0xFFEFEEEE)`
- Light shadow: `Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),`
- Dark shadow: `Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1)`

Code

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
        offset: Offset(-6.0, -6.0),
        blurRadius: 16.0,
      ),
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
        offset: Offset(6.0, 6.0),
        blurRadius: 16.0,
      ),
    ],
    color: Color(0xFFEFEEEE),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
  ),
),
```

## Neumorphic dark

[image]

- Background color: `Color(0xFF292D32)`
- Light shadow: `Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),`
- Dark shadow: `Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4)`

Code

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
        offset: Offset(-6.0, -6.0),
        blurRadius: 16.0,
      ),
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
        offset: Offset(6.0, 6.0),
        blurRadius: 16.0,
      ),
    ],
    color: Color(0xFF292D32),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
  ),
),
```

## Pub packages

- [flutter_neumorphic](http://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic)
- [clay_containers](https://pub.dev/packages/clay_containers)
- [neumorphic](https://pub.dev/packages/neumorphic)
- [nm_generators](https://pub.dev/packages/nm_generators)

## See also

These articles and code were helpful in researching this.

- [Neumorphism in user interfaces](https://uxdesign.cc/neumorphism-in-user-interfaces-b47cef3bf3a6)
- [Neumorphism (Soft UI) in User interface design - Tutorial](https://uxplanet.org/neumorphism-in-user-interface-tutorial-c353698ac5c0)
- [Dark Neumorphism UI Trend 2020](https://dribbble.com/shots/10039597-Dark-Neumorphism-UI-Trend-2020)
- [Neumorphic designs with Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/neumorphic-designs-in-flutter-eab9a4de2059)
- [neuomorphic_container Pub package](https://pub.dev/packages/neuomorphic_container)